# How to show side menu like this on mobile?

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, responsive

How to show side menu like this on mobile?

in image 1 When i touch on left menu (see ping arrow)

image 1:

[image: img1]

It's will show slide menu like in image 2 , how can i do that ?

image 2:

[image: img2]

css or javascript ?

Comment: You can achieve it either way. In css, using input type checkbox can be the trigger. However, it will be cleaner if you use javascript. Just toggling class can achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Jquery plugin for this.

Have a look at [Slick-App-Like-Sliding-Menu-Plugin-With-jQuery-Mmenu](http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Slick-App-Like-Sliding-Menu-Plugin-With-jQuery-Mmenu.html)

Answer (score 0):

May be u should try Materialize.

http://materializecss.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use css and javascript. Both will work fine. If you know how to use bootstrap the quickest way is to add `Responsive navbar` which is described here: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navbar